# Return an array from a VBA function

Tags: vba

I have the following code:

```
Public Function model(s As String) As String()
    s = Replace(Replace(s, "-", ","), " ", "")
    model = Split(s, ",")
End Function
```

Which basically should take an `s` string, for example:

```
s = "031, 603-604, 803-804, 617, 817, 619, 819, 621, 821, 627, 827, 629, 829, 831, 645-646, 845-846, 647-648, 847-848, 649-650, 849-850, 667-668, 867-868, 671-672, 871-872, 677-678, 675-676, 875-876, 679-680"
```

And make an array of codes (models) based upon it. I want to call it in this way:

```
Sub irrelevant()
    Dim s as String
    s = <similar string from the above, but directly input from a worksheet cell>
    tmpArr = model(s)

    Dim iCtr As Long
    For iCtr = 0 To UBound(tmpArr)
        Debug.Print tmpArr(iCtr)
    Next
End sub
```

This throws me an error on `tmpArr = model(s)` line:

```
Compile Error:
Expected array
```

Comment: Works fine for me when I am setting s to be a string. So it most likely is coming from how you are getting it from the sheet. What is the code you use to get the values from the worksheet cell?

Comment: @Sam ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(4, 5)

Comment: And the value in that cell is just simular to the string above?

Comment: 1. `tmpArr` isn't declared and so is type `Variant` by default,  not an array. 2. Easiest way to do this is to change the function to return a variant instead.

Comment: @SOofWXLS. It works fine for me just taking the code straight from here...

Comment: Also rather than have the function return a variant. declare tmpArr as a string array. Which is what VBA should do once it realises what data is going into it if it has not been declared

Comment: @Sam works for me too, but OP might have `Option Explicit` enabled.

Comment: @Sam is write. Without knowing if option explicit is on/off, this code should work. It works at my end with `Option Explicit` not declared. If you choose to declare it, it will accept it as variant variable and array of strings (`tmpArr As Variant` or `tmpArr() As String`) but not array of variants (`tmpArr() As Variant`).

Comment: Which would then through the error of it not being declared. So would not even get to the stage of looking to see if the function was expecting a array. It would simply say "Variable not defined"

Comment: @emihir0  `It works now, thanks Sam` So what is the problem :)

Comment: Well I had to simply add Dim tmpArr() As String... silly of me to forget about that :x.